# How to show linear regression on brushed points in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

**Edited:** I removed to the call to get a dataset from data.world and instead fed in the mtcars dataset which produces the same error of *contrasts can only be applied to factors of 2 or more*

I am learning shiny and wanted to create a plot that gives the linear regression line for both a) the whole plot and b) linear regression line for brushed points on the plot. I would even settle for just showing the summary stats for the regression of the brushed points.

The code below

- plots the user inputs for x and y
- allows the user to brush points
- creates a reactive datasubset of brushed points
- shows summary of the regression for all points
- shows data table of the reactive datasubset of brushed points when a brush is applied
- breaks down when asked to perform a regression on those brushed points for reasons I do not understand...

code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.world)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

#show data from data.world
gcdata_ds <- "https://data.world/llawsonwork/gcdata"
#gcdatafile <- data.world::query(
  #qry_sql("SELECT * FROM gcdataclean"),
  #dataset =gcdata_ds
#)

#datafile <- gcdatafile
#so that you will not need data.world
datafile <-mtcars


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  #Application Layout
  sidebarLayout(

    #Inputs
    sidebarPanel(

      #select variable for y-axis
      selectInput(inputId = "ya",
                 label = "Y-axis",
                 choices = colnames(datafile),
                 selected = "life_expec"
                 ),

      #Select Variable for x axis
      selectInput(inputId = "xa",
                 label = "X-axis",
                 choices = colnames(datafile),
                 selected = "life_expec"
      )
    ),

    #output
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "guilfordplot", brush = "plot_brush"),
      htmlOutput(outputId = "summary"), # summary of lin regress all points
      dataTableOutput(outputId = "brushedtracts"), # data table to make sure brushed points are updating correctly
      textOutput(outputId = "brushedreg") # NOT Working summary of lin reg brushed points 
    )
  )
)

#define server function

server <- function(input, output){

#this was useful in creating the regression model as X was always column 1 and Y was always column  in this dataframe
  datasubset <- reactive({
    req(input$xa)
    req(input$ya)
    data.frame(X = datafile[input$xa], Y = datafile[input$ya])
  })

 #create datasubset of the brushed points
  brushedsubset <- reactive({
    req(input$xa)
    req(input$ya)
    req(input$plot_brush)
    brushedPoints(datafile, brush = input$plot_brush) %>%
      select(input$xa, input$ya)
  })

  #Create plot
  output$guilfordplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = datafile, aes_string(x = input$xa, y = input$ya)) +
      geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm")
  })

  #create summary file
  output$summary <- renderUI({
    model = lm(datasubset()[,2] ~ datasubset()[,1], data = datasubset())
    r2 = format(summary(model)$r.squared, digits = 3)
    txt = paste("The equation of the line is :\nY = ",
                round(coefficients(model)[1],0), " + ",
                round(coefficients(model)[2], 5), "X")

   # str_3 <- format(coef(m)[1], digits = 3)

    str_1 <- txt
    str_2 <- paste("The R^2 value is equal to ", r2)
    HTML(paste(str_1, str_2, sep = '<br/>'))
  })


  # create data table
  output$brushedtracts <- DT::renderDataTable({
   select(brushedsubset(), input$xa, input$ya)
  })

  # create brushed summary stats
  output$brushedreg <- renderText({
    modelbrush = lm(brushedsubset()[,2] ~ brushedsubset()[,1], data = brushedsubset())
    br2 = format(summary(modelbrush)$r.squared, digits = 3)
    btxt = paste("The equation of the line is :\nY = ",
                round(coefficients(modelbrush)[1],0), " + ",
                round(coefficients(modelbrush)[2], 5), "X")
    paste(btxt, ' and the rsquared is: ', br2 )

  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So the code above works for the summary regression of all points for a given x and y input.

But this code does not work for giving me the linear regression of the brushed points and I cannot figure out why because it is the nearly identical for the code for the linear regression of all points.

Any help would be appreciated and it there is a tidyer way of doing the linear regression and summary stats please let me know.

Comment: Your code gives me this (for gcdatafile): Error in auth_token() : 
  API authentication must be configured  before any functions can be invoked.  To configure, use dwapi::configure().

Comment: That error results from not having an API key for data.world the website where the data is stored. The dataset is available at https://data.world/llawsonwork/gcdata as a cvs titled gcdataclean

Comment: As I am retrying it I see that data.world is not as simple of a format to share files as I hoped because even with the link you have sign in. is there a better way to share the dataset?

Comment: removed to the call to data.world and instead used mtcars data frame.

Comment: There is a `gcdatafile` variable in `output$guilfordplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = gcdatafile...` Don't you need to change that to `datafile`?

Comment: Thanks GyD. The perils of haste when modifying code to be posted on here. it should be fixed now.